# Add class in angular on ng-repeat when item is contained on array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On an Angular controller I have an array of events:

```
vm.events = [
  { date: "18-02-2016", name: "event A" },
  { date: "18-02-2016", name: "event C" },
  { date: "24-02-2016", name: "event D" }
];
```

And I have an array of all days in current month:

```
var days = [
  { date: "01-02-2016" },
  { date: "02-02-2016" },
  { date: "03-02-2016" }
  ...
];
```

On my angular view I have the following:

```
<span
  class="day"
  ng-class="{ 'today': isToday(day) }"
  ng-repeat="day in vm.days">{{getDay(day)}}</span>
```

How can I add a class to the span when a day has events, e.g., when the day has at least one record in vm.events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
  <span ng-class="{true:'today', false: 'day' } [isToday(day.date)]">
     {{day.date}} : {{isToday(day.date)}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Check the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4YIM9YZwLgTsBUEDkCWi?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngClass**, the way to do is by adding your condition like:

```
ng-class="{true:'today'}[isToday(day)]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thought might be to write some function that takes a date and then and it determines if that dates has any events by iterating over the events array.

That will result in a lot of unnecessary iteration on each digest cycle. Instead, you can manipulate the data before it's rendered in the ng-repeat. Modify the data such that each day has an array of events. Now you can just check if that day's events array contains any events.

Ideally, I would try and change this on the server, so that data came down in such a fashion. But there's no reason the client can't do it. Here's a simple implementation:

```
angular.forEach(vm.days, function(day) {
  // this modifies the day objects in vm.days, if you didn't want to
  // do that you could copy them and produce a separate array of days
  // with events...
  day.events = vm.findEventsFor(day))
});

vm.findEventsFor(day) {
  var events = [];
  angular.forEach(vm.events, function(event) {
    if (event.date === day.date) {
      events.push(event);
    }
  }
  return events;
}
```

Your `ng-class` might look like this:

```
ng-class="{today: isToday(day), hasEvents: day.events.length > 0}"
```